# What happens if Krosan Verge does not have a land of the specific type to pull?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I crack a [Krosan Verge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKrosan%20Verge%5d) to search for a basic plains and a basic forest, and there is not a basic forest in the deck, what happens?

Comment: This doesn't directly address your question, but I want to point out that Krosan Verge doesn't specify that the lands are "basic".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get just a plains from your library without also finding a forest.

If a card instructs you to search for something specific (in this case, "a Forest card" and "a Plains card"), you can "fail to find" and simply take nothing out of your library. If you are searching for two or more cards, as in this situation, you can find one but not the other, so in the specific case you describe, you can get just a plains from your library and put it onto the battlefield.

This is covered by [rule 701.18b](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Search):

> If a player is searching a hidden zone for cards with a stated quality, such as a card with a certain card type or color, that player isn’t required to find some or all of those cards even if they’re present in that zone.